# Prove improper integral exists and continuously differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

For $x\in(0,\infty)$, let $F(x)=\int_0^\infty\frac{1-e^{-tx}}{t^{\frac{3}{2}}}\ dt$. Show that $F:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ is well-defined, bijective and has continuous non-zero derivative.

I don't know what argument to say about bijectivity. And for derivative exists I suppose we use uniform convergence on compact interval which enables us to interchange limit and integration, but does that mean we have to cut $(0,\infty)$ into three parts? As for showing derivative is continuous, it just sounds like a lot of calculation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $F$ is well defined, you have to study separately the two singularities of $$f(t) = \frac{1-e^{-xt}}{t^{3/2}}$$
For $t \to 0^+$ you have
$$\frac{1-e^{-xt}}{t^{3/2}} \sim \frac{xt}{t^{3/2}} = \frac{x}{t^{1/2}}$$
since $\int_0^1 \frac{x}{t^{1/2}} dt$ converges, you have convergence of $\int_0^1 f(t) dt$.

For $t \to + \infty$ you have
$$\frac{1-e^{-xt}}{t^{3/2}} \sim \frac{1}{t^{3/2}}$$
since $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{t^{3/2}} dt$ converges, you have convergence of $\int_1^{+\infty} f(t) dt$.

This shows that $F$ is well defined for all $x$.

Now, for $0<x_1 < x_2$ and for all $t > 0$ you have
$$\frac{1-e^{-x_1t}}{t^{3/2}}<\frac{1-e^{-x_2t}}{t^{3/2}}$$
thus integrating you have
$$\int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{1-e^{-x_1t}}{t^{3/2}} \mathrm dt <\int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{1-e^{-x_2t}}{t^{3/2}} \mathrm dt$$

This shows that $F$ is strictly increasing on $(0, + \infty)$. In particular it is injective. To show that it is bijective it is enough to prove continuity. To show that $F$ is continuous, it is enough to prove that $F$ is differentiable.
This seems quite complicated.

HOWEVER:
Note that, if you call $u=xt$, then your function becomes:
$$F(x)=\sqrt{x} \int_{0}^{+ \infty} \frac{1-e^{-u}}{u^{3/2}}  \mathrm du = F(1) \sqrt x$$
which is a well-known function: continuous, strictly increasing, differentiable and bijective.

Comment: Say we didn't notice that $F(x) = F(1)\sqrt{x}$ and we wanted to differentiate $F$ by dominating $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-e^{-tx}}{t^{3/2}}\right) = \frac{e^{-tx}}{\sqrt{t}}$$
by an integrable function on $(0,+\infty)$ independent of $x$. I haven't been able to come up with the dominating function. Clearly $\frac{e^{-tx}}{\sqrt{t}} \le \frac1{\sqrt{t}}$ for $t \le 1$ but for $t \ge 1$ what to dominate it with?

Comment: For $t \ge 1$, $\frac{e^{-tx}}{\sqrt{t}} \le e^{-tx}$.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not independent of $x$. And you cannot say $e^{-tx} \le e^{-t}$ for $x < 1$. My other attempt was $$\frac{e^{-tx}}{\sqrt{t}} \le \frac1{\sqrt{t}(1+tx)}$$
but again I was unable to eliminate $x$.

Comment: @mechanodroid If we had $e^{-tx}/\sqrt t \le g(t)$ everwhere, then letting $x\to 0^+$ gives $1/\sqrt t\le g(t)$ for all $t>0,$ which implies $g\notin L^1(0,\infty).$

Comment: @mechanodroid However, if $a>0,$ then for $(x,t)\in [a,\infty)\times (0,\infty),$ we have

$$e^{-tx}/\sqrt t \le e^{-ta}/\sqrt t.$$

That is enough to use differentiation through the integral sign.

Comment: @zhw. That's a neat trick, thanks a lot.

Comment: If we didn't notice the explicit formula for $F$, simply knowing $F$ is continuous cannot let us conclude $\lim_{x\to 0}F(x)=F(\lim_{x\to 0}x)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=F(\lim_{x\to \infty}x)$, can we? Since $0,\infty$ aren't in the domain and aren't points of continuity.

Comment: @mechanodroid What argument are you using for changing the limit and integral sign? Why do you have to get rid of $x$ in the dominating function?

Comment: @FluffySkye Well yes, $F$ is not defined at $0, \infty$. The argument relies on the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, I elaborated in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of the integrand is
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-e^{-tx}}{t^{3/2}}\right) = \frac{e^{-tx}}{\sqrt{t}}$$
We claim that
$$F'(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt$$
for all $x > 0$.

Fix $a > 0$ and notice that for $x \ge a$ we have
$$\frac{e^{-tx}}{\sqrt{t}} \le \frac{e^{-ta}}{\sqrt{t}} \le \frac1{\sqrt{t}}\chi_{(0,1]}(t) + e^{-ta}\chi_{[1,\infty)}(t)$$
the latter being an integrable function on $(0,\infty)$.
For any such $x$ we have
$$F'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{F(x+h) - F(x)}h = \lim_{h\to 0} \int_0^\infty \frac1h\left[\frac{1-e^{-t(x+h)}}{t^{3/2}} - \frac{1-e^{-tx}}{t^{3/2}}\right]\,dt$$
The mean value theorem implies that $\exists \theta(h) \in (x,x+h)$ such that $$\frac1h\left[\frac{1-e^{-t(x+h)}}{t^{3/2}} - \frac{1-e^{-tx}}{t^{3/2}}\right] = \frac{e^{-t\theta}}{\sqrt{t}}$$
so $$F'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t\theta(h)}}{\sqrt{t}} \,dt =  \int_0^\infty \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-t\theta(h)}}{\sqrt{t}} \,dt = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt$$
We were able to swap the integral and the limit according to the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem since 
$$\left|\frac{e^{-t\theta(h)}}{\sqrt{t}} \right| \le \frac1{\sqrt{t}}\chi_{(0,1]}(t) + e^{-ta}\chi_{[1,\infty)}(t), \quad\forall t > 0$$
Notice that it is important that the dominating function does not depend on $h$ in any way.

Since $a > 0$ is arbitrary, we conclude $F'(x) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{\sqrt{t}}\,dt$ for all $x > 0$.

---

For surjectivity it suffices to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = \infty$. This together with continuity yields the desired result via the intermediate value theorem.

For $x \le 1$ we have
$$\frac{1-e^{-tx}}{t^{3/2}} \le \frac1{\sqrt{t}}\chi_{(0,1]}(t) + \frac1{t^{3/2}}\chi_{[1,\infty)}(t)$$
having used $e^{-tx} \ge 1-tx$. The latter function is integrable on $(0,\infty)$ so Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem implies
$$\lim_{x\to 0} F(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} \int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-tx}}{t^{3/2}}\,dt = \int_0^\infty \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{-tx}}{t^{3/2}}\,dt = \int_0^\infty 0 \,dt = 0$$

You already know that for $x_1,x_2 \in (0,\infty)$ with $x_1 < x_2$ we have $$\frac{1-e^{-tx_1}}{t^{3/2}} < \frac{1-e^{-tx_2}}{t^{3/2}}$$

Lebesgue monotone convergence theorem thus implies
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} F(x) = \lim_{x\to \infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{1-e^{-tx}}{t^{3/2}}\,dt = \int_0^\infty \lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1-e^{-tx}}{t^{3/2}}\,dt = \int_0^\infty \frac1{t^{3/2}} \,dt = \infty$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I just learnt improper integral and this is the first excercie I got, I just want to know every detail.

Comment: But regarding surjectivity, without having the explicit formula, only knowing injectivity  and continuity is not enough, is it?

Comment: @FluffySkye It isn't, we also need to show that $\lim_{x\to 0} F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x) = \infty$ and then the result follows from the intermediate value theorem. Have a look, I added it in the answer.